# Save content in Google storage file

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-api-nodejs-client

I try to save a generated file from in-memory JSON to google storage by Nodejs.

The saving process to GCS working well and it's creating the file but its throw error.
(The process work because I didn't catch the error).

As I understand the error come from **`storage.bucket(bucket).file(filename)`**,

How can I avoid the exception?

```
   let file = storage.bucket('dev').file('widgets/test.json');
   file.setMetadata({
        contentType: contentType,',
        cacheControl: 'public,no-cache,max-age=0',
    });
    return await file.save(json.stringify(content))`
```

Error -
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No such object: dev/widgets/test.json`

Comment: Are you sure it's not because you're trying to set metadata on a file that doesn't exist yet?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error and after spending sometime I have found a way to pass the contentType. I hope it would help someone someday!

```
        // upload the file
        var idsObj = {"ids": ids};
        var idsJSONStr = JSON.stringify(idsObj); // convert object to json string

        const file = storage
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .file(fileName);

        const isSaved = await file.save(idsJSONStr, {
            contentType: 'application/json'
        }).then(function(err) {
            if (err && err.length != 0) {
                console.error("The file is not saved", err);
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });

        console.log('The file is saved: ', isSaved);
```

Comment: From my testing, `contentType` isn't required to create or update JSON via `file.save()`

Answer (score -1):

I found this example on the Node.js [Official GCP repo](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/uploadFile.js).

```
function main(bucketName = 'my-bucket', filename = './local/path/to/file.txt') {
  // [START storage_upload_file]
  /**
   * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
   */
  // const bucketName = 'Name of a bucket, e.g. my-bucket';
  // const filename = 'Local file to upload, e.g. ./local/path/to/file.txt';

  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  // Creates a client
  const storage = new Storage();

  async function uploadFile() {
    // Uploads a local file to the bucket
    await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
      // Support for HTTP requests made with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
      gzip: true,
      // By setting the option `destination`, you can change the name of the
      // object you are uploading to a bucket.
      metadata: {
        // Enable long-lived HTTP caching headers
        // Use only if the contents of the file will never change
        // (If the contents will change, use cacheControl: 'no-cache')
        cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
      },
    });

    console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
  }

  uploadFile().catch(console.error);
  // [END storage_upload_file]
}
```

I think that this is related with the context of the async function, but if you use the GCP method this should work fine

Comment: Thank you, but as I saw it's to uploads a local file to the bucket.

Comment: what do you want to upload?

Comment: in-memory JSON object